# Inverse association in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecord models. `Idea` and `User`. There's an association between the two that is working like `User.idea`.

The User model currently save `lat` and `lng` coordinates from the user.

From ideas controller, I would like to query all ideas that match a certain location. I'm not how can I do this inverse join query in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
Idea.joins(:user).where(user: {lat: some_lat, lng: some_lng}).all
```

`some_lat`/`some_lng` can be a Range. Rails will handle the magic.

Comment: If you have exact latitude and longitude this could be a good solution (though rarely it's possible to be exact with floats/decimal)

Comment: He should be able to pass a range: `some_lat = 56.311018..56.711018`. And the generation of these could be done via a method.

Comment: It's out of the scope of the question. `some_lat` can be a Range. Rails will handle the magic.

Answer (score 1):

First: How do you find the wanted locations? Probably you could use something like Geocoder (there is a [RailsCast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)).

Now I'll have a similar problem in the near future but for the moment I thought I'll probably do it in two steps (double query):

```
@users = User.near(params[:location]).pluck(:id)
@ideas = Ideas.where(:user_id => @users)
```

This way you get the ideas near the wanted location (I've used the Geocoder method here but you could get the users in a different way).

Note: I'm assuming a user has many ideas and an Idea belongs to a user

Comment: You could just tell rails to load the ideas belonging to the users with `.includes( :ideas )`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to search for all the users which match your location and include the ideas while loading.

```
# first about the near by:
def close_to( position )
  (position-0.2)..(position+0.2)
end

@users = User.where( :lat => close_to(some_lat), :lng => close_to(some_lng) ).includes( :ideas )

# if you need all the ideas:
@ideas = []
@users.each do |user|
  @ideas += user.ideas
end
```

Otherwise you have in the users array all the ideas sorted by the user. Or did I miss your question?